# How to check whether gitlab agent is successfully installed?

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to check whether the gitlab agent is successfully installed for kubernetes connection.
How can I check that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check the GitLab Agent logs with ```kubectl logs gitlab-agent``` . If you see messages about successful connections to the Kubernetes cluster, the agent is running and connecting correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the way you installed it, one way to check is to see if the pod is running correctly by verifying the `READY` status by doing a `kubectl get pods --namespace gitlab` or `kubectl get pods --namespace gitlab-agent`

You can find more information here: [Installing the agent for Kubernetes](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/install/)